# Can Asp.Net UserControls know if they're being added 'late' to the control hierarchy?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, dynamic-usercontrols

I have a user control that uses the standard `if(!IsPostBack){//initialize myself}` paradigm to avoid re-doing initialization during postbacks (so, trading fewer DB hits for increased ViewState usage).  That approach serves me well most of the time but there's one place where I want to add this control to the control hierarchy 'late', during a postback.

This, of course, causes the initialization logic to fail, and the control to be rendered in an uninitialized state.

What guard should I be using to determine whether I should initialize, since `!IsPostBack` isn't cutting it?  I could set a flag during `LoadViewState`, but that seems a bit hackish.  What I'd like to find is some condition that only happens when a control is first added to the control hierarchy, and key on that. Does such a condition exist?

[edit] Sample pseudocode follows for the containing page:

```
protected void Page_Prerender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Controls.Add(LoadControl("some_control.ascx"));
}
```

Is there a way for `some_control` to know it's been added late?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further searches did not lead me to a general solution to this problem.  What I ended up doing was setting a flag in `Page_LoadViewState` which suppressed the control's initialization - effectively the same thing as guarding the initialization with `!IsPostBack`, but a bit more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the constructor to initialize your child controls? (or create a Initialize method) Then you control when the control is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you to understand your problem:
“…what if a control is created in an event handler and dynamically added to the control tree? In that case, the control plays catch-up. As soon as it is added to the control tree, it starts to execute its phases until it reaches the current phase of the page…”

More informations here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/vga/archive/2003/08/11/23498.aspx

Comment: That blog article actually misrepresents the situation a little; the control isn't playing catch-up, it's forcibly being caught up - and what I'm after is a mechanism to figure out when I'm in that state.

Comment: Maybe doing to something like that would help you:

protected void Page_Prerender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyControl control = LoadControl("MyControl") as MyControl;
    control.MustInitialize = true;
    Controls.Add( control );
}

Comment: Ended up solving this problem in almost this way, but without having to define a public MustInitialize.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a concept of adding a control for the "first" time, because remember that every single time you request a page, a **new** page object is created, with all **new** control instances.  Previously created control instances aren't being added to your new page object.

Why does the initialization logic fail?  Perhaps if you posted that code we could suggest something - it doesn't seem like that should necessarily have to be the case.

Comment: I know I get a new instance of all the controls on each postback - what I'm trying to figure out is whether a usercontrol can know that it was added to the control hierarchy out-of-sequence (i.e. via Controls.Add) during any particular postback.